# How to make D3 gauge chart in Qlikview extension

Tags: d3.js, qlikview

I have made a gauge chart using D3.js and it is working perfectly. However, when I am trying to add the same javascript code to render the same chart in a Qlikview extension, it is not working.

Can anyone please help me to find out where I am going wrong? I am attaching the code of the Script.js file below:

```
 Qva.LoadScript("QlikView/Examples/Gauge/d3.min.js", function () {



/*
  function loadGoogleCoreChart() {
   google.load('visualization', '1', {
    packages: ['corechart'],
    callback: googleCoreChartLoaded
});
 }

  function googleCoreChartLoaded() {
 */
    Qva.AddExtension('QlikView/Examples/Gauge', function () {
//this.Element.innerHTML = "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"http://d3js.org/d3.v2.min.js\"></script>"
//this.Element.innerHTML = "";

var gauge = function(container, configuration) {

var that = {};
var config = {
    size                        : 200,
    clipWidth                   : 200,
    clipHeight                  : 110,
    ringInset                   : 20,
    ringWidth                   : 20,

pointerWidth                : 10,
pointerTailLength           : 5,
pointerHeadLengthPercent    : 0.9,

minValue                    : 0,
maxValue                    : 10,

minAngle                    : -90,
maxAngle                    : 90,

transitionMs                : 750,

majorTicks                  : 5,
labelFormat                 : d3.format(',g'),
labelInset                  : 10,

arcColorFn                  : d3.interpolateHsl(d3.rgb('#e8e2ca'), d3.rgb('#3e6c0a'))
};

var range = undefined;
var r = undefined;
var pointerHeadLength = undefined;
var value = 0;

var svg = undefined;
var arc = undefined;
var scale = undefined;
var ticks = undefined;
var tickData = undefined;
var pointer = undefined;

var donut = d3.layout.pie();

function deg2rad(deg) {
    return deg * Math.PI / 180;
}

function newAngle(d) {
    var ratio = scale(d);
    var newAngle = config.minAngle + (ratio * range);
    return newAngle;
}

function configure(configuration) {
    var prop = undefined;
    for ( prop in configuration ) {
        config[prop] = configuration[prop];
    }



range = config.maxAngle - config.minAngle;
    r = config.size / 2;
    pointerHeadLength = Math.round(r * config.pointerHeadLengthPercent);

    // a linear scale that maps domain values to a percent from 0..1
    scale = d3.scale.linear()
        .range([0,1])
        .domain([config.minValue, config.maxValue]);

    ticks = scale.ticks(config.majorTicks);
    tickData = d3.range(config.majorTicks).map(function() {return 1/config.majorTicks;});

    arc = d3.svg.arc()
        .innerRadius(r - config.ringWidth - config.ringInset)
        .outerRadius(r - config.ringInset)
        .startAngle(function(d, i) {
            var ratio = d * i;
            return deg2rad(config.minAngle + (ratio * range));
        })
        .endAngle(function(d, i) {
            var ratio = d * (i+1);
            return deg2rad(config.minAngle + (ratio * range));
        });
}
that.configure = configure;

function centerTranslation() {
    return 'translate('+r +','+ r +')';
}

function isRendered() {
    return (svg !== undefined);
}
that.isRendered = isRendered;

function render(newValue) {
    svg = d3.select(container)
        .append('svg:svg')
            .attr('class', 'gauge')
            .attr('width', config.clipWidth)
            .attr('height', config.clipHeight);

    var centerTx = centerTranslation();

    var arcs = svg.append('g')
            .attr('class', 'arc')
            .attr('transform', centerTx);

    arcs.selectAll('path')
            .data(tickData)
        .enter().append('path')
            .attr('fill', function(d, i) {
                return config.arcColorFn(d * i);
            })
            .attr('d', arc);




var lg = svg.append('g')
            .attr('class', 'label')
            .attr('transform', centerTx);
    lg.selectAll('text')
            .data(ticks)
        .enter().append('text')
            .attr('transform', function(d) {
                var ratio = scale(d);
                var newAngle = config.minAngle + (ratio * range);
                return 'rotate(' +newAngle +') translate(0,' +(config.labelInset - r) +')';
            })
            .text(config.labelFormat);

    var lineData = [ [config.pointerWidth / 2, 0], 
                    [0, -pointerHeadLength],
                    [-(config.pointerWidth / 2), 0],
                    [0, config.pointerTailLength],
                    [config.pointerWidth / 2, 0] ];
    var pointerLine = d3.svg.line().interpolate('monotone');
    var pg = svg.append('g').data([lineData])
            .attr('class', 'pointer')
            .attr('transform', centerTx);

    pointer = pg.append('path')
        .attr('d', pointerLine/*function(d) { return pointerLine(d) +'Z';}*/ )
        .attr('transform', 'rotate(' +config.minAngle +')');

    update(newValue === undefined ? 0 : newValue);
}
that.render = render;

function update(newValue, newConfiguration) {
    if ( newConfiguration  !== undefined) {
        configure(newConfiguration);
    }
    var ratio = scale(newValue);
    var newAngle = config.minAngle + (ratio * range);
    pointer.transition()
        .duration(config.transitionMs)
        .ease('elastic')
        .attr('transform', 'rotate(' +newAngle +')');
}
that.update = update;

configure(configuration);

return that;
};


 function onDocumentReady() {
var powerGauge = gauge(this.Element, {
    size: 300,
    clipWidth: 300,
    clipHeight: 300,
    ringWidth: 60,
    maxValue: 10,
    transitionMs: 4000,
});
alert("Some Text");
powerGauge.render();

function updateReadings() {
    // just pump in random data here...
    powerGauge.update(Math.random() * 10);
}

// every few seconds update reading values
updateReadings();
setInterval(function() {
    updateReadings();
}, 5 * 1000);
}

 if ( !window.isLoaded ) {
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    onDocumentReady();
}, false);
 } else {
onDocumentReady();
}

});

});
```

Please help me with this as I am unable to find out the glitch.